# Amazon AWS- Gunicorn is throwing a lacks both error whenever I start systemctl

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, amazon-ec2, gunicorn

I am unable to start the gunicorn3 using systemctl for some reason. Below are my commands written in gunicorn 3:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=TodoApp
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/TodoApp/project1-na2165-hw1714-ab7232-rdl394-rk3194
ExecStart=/home/TodoApp/project1-na2165-hw1714-ab7232-rdl394-rk3194/TodoAppEnv/bin/gunicorn3--access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/TodoApp/project1-na2165-hw1714-ab7232-rdl394-rk3194/Todo/Todo.sock Todo.wsgi:application

[install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I tried changing the name of the user (which I assume can be anything we want) the working directory and the exec start multiple times. However, I still get the following error:

```
systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Service lacks both
```

EDIT: 
Sorry I couldn't see the entire error before. The full error says:

> gunicorn.service: Service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting.
>   Refusing.

Comment: Please show the whole error. Lacks both what?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Sorry about that! I just made the edit in the main question.